# Is there an efficient way to write the code snippet without for loops in R?

Tags: r, performance, coding-efficiency

Is there an efficient way to write the below code in R?

v is a matrix of length n x n.

```
k <- matrix(0, n, n-2)
for (i in seq(n)){
  for (j in seq(n-2)) {
    k[i,j] = v[i, j]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you can just subset: `k <- v[1:n, 1:(n-2)]`

Comment: or even shorter: `k <- v[, 1:(n-2)]`